# go-mysql: authentication plugin not supported while connecting from go app container to mysql container

Tags: mysql, windows, ubuntu, docker, go

I am porting my linux docker environment from my mac to my pc laptop.  I have 2 docker images, one is a `mysql:latest` database image, the other is a `go:alpine` application server image.

On my mac, I use bash scripts to pass in environment variables to the app server to compose the database connection string to mysql.

The connection string is:

```
root:password@tcp(mysql_host:3306)/dbname
```

The database connection is successful when I run this on my mac, but not on my PC.

On `Windows 10`, I have installed `Ubuntu` and `Docker for Windows`.  In `bash`, I've installed the docker client and I am able to use the docker cli to connect to my Windows Docker host by setting the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable.

I have created a custom docker network that I pass to my 2 containers via the `--network` flag so they can see each other and I have verified that they are indeed able to resolve their container names.

The connection string that my app server is using is exactly the same, but returns the following error:

```
this authentication plugin is not supported
```

The line in my go code returning this error is:

```
db, err = sql.Open("mysql", dbConnStr)
```

What am I missing?  What authentication plugin?

Here is the output of `docker info` on my PC:

```
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 27
Server Version: 18.04.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs
Operating System: Docker for Windows
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 6
Total Memory: 3.837GiB
Name: linuxkit-00155d016401
ID: JXLB:YHLO:J6XO:H66P:X7LQ:RF2I:Z3AC:FPLY:OCLQ:DSYU:H4CR:W2DD
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 19
 Goroutines: 36
 System Time: 2018-04-23T06:06:31.2274774Z
 EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 5):

MySQL image on docker hub changes "latest" tag from 5.7 to 8 recently (2018/04/20), which has lots of breaking changes. Using "mysql:5.7" instead of "mysql" should solve your problem.

Comment: at this point i've given up on the porting effort though.  i hope one day this becomes less painful, but that day hasn't yet arrived.