# How to connect a Docker container of Grafana to a Docker conatiner of MySql?

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, dockerfile, grafana

I wish to set up 2 docker containers: grafana and mysql and to allow queries from the grafana to the mysql db. 
I have an AWS machine, in which I built the following folders structure:

```
- docker
  - docker-compose.yml
  - grafana:
    - config.ini
    - dashboards:
      - grafana_dashboard.json
    - provisioning:
      - dashboards:
        - all.yml
      - datasources:
        - all.yml
    - Dockerfile
  - mysql:
    - dbcreation.sql
    - Dockerfile
  - dashboards:
  - import.sh
```

the content of the docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db-service:
    build: './mysql'
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.1.3

  grafana-service:
    build: './grafana'
    container_name: grafana
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "XXX1"
      GF_AUTH_PROXY_ENABLED: "true"
      GF_SECURITY_DATA_SOURCE_PROXY_WHITELIST: 172.16.1.3:3306
      GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED: "true"
      GF_LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
    depends_on:
      - db-service
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.1.4


networks:
  net:
    external: true

volumes:
  grafanadata:
    driver: local
  mysqldata:
```

The dockerfile for the grafana:

```
FROM grafana/grafana:5.2.2
ADD ./provisioning /etc/grafana/provisioning
ADD ./dashboards /var/lib/grafana/dashboards
ENV DS_DB "grafana"
```

The content of the mysql/Dockerfile is:

```
FROM mysql:8.0.12

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="XXX2"
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE="grafana"

ADD ./dbcreation.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dbcreation.sql
EXPOSE 3306
```

The grafana_dashboard.json file has the exported json from the Grafana I had set up locally on my own computer. 
The dbcreation.sql file has the exported data from the local DB I had set up locally on my own computer.

I'm running the following commands:

```
docker network create --gateway 172.16.1.1 --subnet 172.16.1.0/24 net
docker-compose up --build
```

I'm getting an error: "The authentication plugin is not supported" 
[image: The authentication plugin is not supported]

when turning the log level of Grafana to debug I'm seeing this:

```
t=2018-08-19T10:55:20+0000 lvl=dbug msg=getEngine logger=tsdb.mysql connection="root:XXX2@tcp(172.16.1.3:3306)/grafana?collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci&parseTime=true&loc=UTC&allowNativePasswords=true"

t=2018-08-19T10:55:47+0000 lvl=eror msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin method=POST path=/api/tsdb/query status=500 remote_addr=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX time_ms=2 size=195 referer=http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000/datasources/edit/1
```

I have used the following sources already to set this up: 
https://ops.tips/blog/initialize-grafana-with-preconfigured-dashboards/

https://storage.pardot.com/138181/61672/mysql_on_docker_how_to_containerize_your_database.pdf

Any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated here:

> [go-mysql: authentication plugin not supported while connecting from go app container to mysql container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974372/go-mysql-authentication-plugin-not-supported-while-connecting-from-go-app-conta)

The problem was compatibility between the Grafana versions and the MySQL version. 
Once moving to docker image mysql:5.7 (had to migrate the data too) - the issue was resolved (need to also change the COLLATION and CHAR_SET in the DB to downgrade from version 8.0.12 to 5.7).